# Likert Plot legend names for response

Tags: r, plot, likert

I have developed a script to plot a Likert scale. The Script works properly and the plot is correct. I want to change the response label which would be, 
"Strongly Disagree","Disagree","Slightly Disagree","Slightly Agree","Agree", "Strongly Agree" in an orderly list.
I have tried different solutions but none seems to work

```
Q1 <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\users\\Desktop\\Survey Responses\\Business Survey\\BusinessLikert.xlsx")

df <- data.frame(respondent = c(Q1$Respondent), Score = c(Q1$Q1))

df1 <- likert(items=df[,2, drop = FALSE], nlevels = 6)

summary(df1)

likert.bar.plot(df1)

likert.density.plot(df1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of the `likert` function (`?likert::likert`), the columns of the data.frame in `items` should be *factors*. The level names then specify the response labels used in the derived likert plots. Since your data is not reproducible, consider the following artificial example:

```r
library(likert)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Score = factor(sample(1:6, size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Slightly Disagree", "Slightly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")))
(df_likert <- likert(items = df))
#>    Item Strongly Disagree Disagree Slightly Disagree Slightly Agree Agree
#> 1 Score                19       18                12             15    15
#>   Strongly Agree
#> 1             21

likert.bar.plot(df_likert)
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** for multiple (e.g. numeric) columns representing individual response groups in the data.frame, recode the columns as factors first and then apply the `likert` function to the recoded data.frame:

```r
## initial data.frame of integers
df <- data.frame(
  sapply(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), function(x) sample(1:6, size = 100, replace = TRUE))
)

## recode each column as a factor
df_factor <- as.data.frame(
  lapply(df, function(x) factor(x, 
      labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Slightly Disagree", 
                 "Slightly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))
  )
)

(df_likert <- likert(items = df_factor))
#>   Item Strongly Disagree Disagree Slightly Disagree Slightly Agree Agree
#> 1   Q1                19       18                12             15    15
#> 2   Q2                19       16                19             18    15
#> 3   Q3                18       15                 8             21    20
#>   Strongly Agree
#> 1             21
#> 2             13
#> 3             18

likert.bar.plot(df_likert)
```

[image: Likert plot multiple groups]

Comment: ...and you could use something like this to convert the existing 1:6 into the respective factor: `df$Score_factor = factor(df$Score, labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Slightly Disagree", "Slightly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))`

Comment: Thanks Joris for your help. I do not get where is should place the input of my data in your script the 2 lines below Q1 <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\users\\Desktop\\Survey Responses\\Business Survey\\BusinessLikert.xlsx")

df <- data.frame(respondent = c(Q1$Respondent), Score = c(Q1$Q1)).

Comment: As @JonSpring commented, you can convert the existing Score column in your data.frame to a factor with `factor` and specify its level-names. You can read more about factors in R here: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html

Comment: Forgot to mention the data input is a 11 colums Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 etc with the response scores from the survey. In total 47 responses for each column, so for instance, Q1 has 47 cell with responses between 1 and 6

Comment: As is, your data is not reproducible, consider including (part of) your data in the question with `dput` or include an artificially created dataset with similar structure, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @user11557166 I included an example that recodes multiple columns of a data.frame as factors before calling the `likert` function